# delivering a website to a company

Tags: java

i want to create a website for a company, how should i deliver it to them?
thanks

Comment: By courier; packaged in a vintage wooden box. Wrapped in gold glittering paper, with a bottle of champagne.

Comment: @Pekka, be nice. Obviously Mahdi is a beginner and this holds for asking questions as well.

Comment: @chicco yeah. But the question *is* extremely hazy bordering unanswerable, and I never make snarky comments if the OP isn't being helped already (which he is).

Comment: @Pekka: Nice idea. Maybe I will do that for a future release of one of our products ;)

Answer (score 5):

Wasn't it mentioned in the requirements? Why don't you just e-mail them and ask? I'd imagine either on a disc, thumb drive or FTP would be fine. This is an odd question.

Comment: i'm a beginner, i don't know how to install their server, and how to config it, and how to run my project on their systems.

Comment: @Mahdi and how are *we* supposed to help the situation, not knowing a thing about your client's systems?

Comment: Mahdi, then you need a more experienced person than you on the team

Comment: @Thor that probably is the correct answer here.

Comment: @Pekka, making it an answer then :)

Answer (score 5):

You need a more experienced person than yourself on the team.

Comment: I would make that a "may need" - one never knows the OP's situation for sure. But from the sound of what Mahdi says, this seems to be true.

Comment: Possibly the best answer, at least after incorporating Pekka's comment.

Answer (score 2):

Either they take the responsibility for getting a web server or they expect it from you. If they do, ask them for the access to their test and productive environment. If they don't have a test environment you should suggest to create one. You will need it sooner or later to perform changes so they can approve them before making them public. (IMHO)

**Edit:** Of course, as mentioned by rmx, you should clarify with your customer whether or not they expect you take responsibility for a web server. Be aware that if you take responsibility for that, the customer will make you responsible for availability, security and backup as well, so in your case it's probably better to let that up to the company.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that should be discussed with the company. Maybe upload it directly to their server, giving them the source code and instructions to install it...